# How to download file in Amazon S3 storage using only a unique id without subfolder name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i want to download a file from Amazon S3 using only a certain unique id i can use from it's api, without using a folder or subfolder name. I created a folder/subfolder structure with hierarchy levels to organize the files.
The same of what I did in Google Drive API v3, regardless of which the folder or subfolder name or hierarchy level of folders the file was saved, i can download the file using only the fileid.
i haven't read yet about the file versioning docs since there are tons to read.
any help would greatly be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to access the object with a Unique ID rather than the actual `Key` of the object? Is this for some form of security? If you can tell us more about _what_ you are trying to achieve (rather than _how_), then we might be able to suggest an alternative.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the aws s3 always requires folder or subfolder name aside from bucket name. in google drive, regardless of the folder name, i can download the file using only the fileid. i cannot have the same folder structure in aws s3, all files are in the root of the bucket name. or is there something i can use in the file versioning?

Comment: The "unique name" of objects in Amazon S3 is known as the `Key`. No two objects can have the same Key. A key can contain a slash (eg `invoices/january.txt`), in which case the `invoices/` part is known as a `Prefix`. You can _think_ of it as a folder, but folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3. You can store an object in a 'folder' even if the folder doesn't exist, because the `Key` defines the full path of an object. So, the `Key` is the unique identifier of an object, including the full path (which is actually part of the Key).

Comment: then thats the Key to my solution :) thanks John.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with S3. You [need to know](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object.html) the bucket name (`--bucket`) and full key (`--key`) of the file you want to download. Since a given file can have multiple versions, you can also provide a version id (`--version-id`).

Comment: i want to implement nearly the same as the google drive which only requires fileid to download the file, aside from the credentials like bucket name. probably a different design in s3.

Comment: @ian so why not use Google drive? Seems as more suited for you than s3.

Comment: i'm currently using google drive, i wanted to implement the same in s3, it's just that s3 has a different design.

Comment: @ Marcin, i appreciate your answer, great help. thanks a lot.